# How can I aggregated trait behaviors together in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to take the behaviors of two traits and aggregate them together into some new thing which can be used to constrain other structures, enums, etc.

Here is an example: Combine the behavior of `Any` with some other trait. The intended purpose is to combine the `downcast` and `is` behaviors of `Any` with some other concept, in this case a function which returns the name of an object.

```
use std::any::Any;

trait Named {
    
    fn get_name(&self) -> String;
}

// Combine the behaviors of `Any` with the trait `Named`
trait DynamicDispatchTrait : Any + Send + Sync + 'static + Named {
    
}

struct MyType {
    
    my_name: String,
}
```

How can I mark the structure `MyType` as "something which behaves as `trait DynamicDispatchTrait`?

My first thought was that `MyType` should implement this trait. That doesn't seem to work:

```
impl DynamicDispatchTrait for MyType {
    
    fn get_name(&self) -> String {
        return format!("my_name_is:{}", self.my_name);
    }
}
```

Here's why:

```
method `get_name` is not a member of trait `DynamicDispatchTrait`
```

The ultimate objective is to be able to write a function like this:

```
fn dynamic_function(dynamic: Box<dyn DynamicDispatchTrait>) -> String {
    
    if let Some(thing) = dynamic.downcast_ref::<MyType>() {
        // ok
    }
    else {
        println!("error!");
        return String::from("error");
    }
    
    // ok ... operate dynamically
    let s = dynamic.get_name();
    return s;
}
```

---

Attempting to implement each trait independently reduces the number of compiler errors:

```
struct MyType {
    
    my_name: String,
}

// Implement trait Named separately
impl Named for MyType {
    
    fn get_name(&self) -> String {
        return format!("my_name_is:{}", self.my_name);
    }
}

// Implement trait DynamicDispatchTrait separately
impl DynamicDispatchTrait for MyType {  }

// Any not implemented?
```

This doesn't quite solve all the issues. The compiler now says:

```
no method named `downcast_ref` found for struct
`Box<(dyn DynamicDispatchTrait + 'static)>` in the current scope
```

I would have thought that occurs because there is no `impl Any for MyType`.

Attempting to add that doesn't quite work.

```
impl Any for MyType {  }
```

```
conflicting implementations of trait `Any` for type `MyType`

...

note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
 - impl<T> Any for T
 where T: 'static, T: ?Sized;
```

Is there a solution to the problem I am attempting to solve?

---

#### Trait Aggregation / Requirements Example:

This looks to behave in a way which is analogous to inheritance.

The point here being that `MyTraitCombo`, when used in the context of a "trait object" has a vtable which permits dispatch of both the functions from the two traits it "inherits" from. ("Inherits" = "satisfies the requirements" / "trait bounds" of.)

```
trait MyTrait1 {
    
    fn my_function_1(&self) -> String {
        
        String::from("function_1")
    }
}

trait MyTrait2 {

    fn my_function_2(&self) -> String {
        
        String::from("function-2")
    }
}

trait MyTraitCombo : MyTrait1 + MyTrait2 {
    

}

// note works without &
fn my_dynamic(argument: Box<&dyn MyTraitCombo>) -> String {
    
    let s1 = argument.my_function_1();
    let s2 = argument.my_function_2();
    
    format!("{}-{}", s1, s2)   
}

impl MyTraitCombo for i64 {
    
}

impl MyTrait1 for i64 {  }

impl MyTrait2 for i64 {  }

fn main() {
    
    let arg = 0i64;
    let s = my_dynamic(Box::new(&arg)); // note works without &
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Comment: It feels like you are trying to force OOP patterns onto a non-OOP language. I'm afraid you will get frustrated pretty quickly with this approach.

Comment: *"demonstrates that Rust does support trait inheritance"* - This is not inheritance, nothing gets inherited. It is more like trait requirements. You cannot simply implement `MyTraitCombo` for something that doesn't implement `MyTrait1`, like inheritance would. It's more like trait dependency than inheritance.

Comment: *"because there is no `impl Any` for `MyType`"* - `Any` is [automatically implemented for all types that are `'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#impl-Any-for-T).

Comment: @Finomnis From your last comment, that suggests a requirement that the traits discussed above all be `'static` ?

Comment: @Finomnis I have re-worded the subsection title to make it clearer

Comment: I'd rather say the objects that implement the trait have to be `'static`, meaning, they do not contain references to things ouside of themselves. That's because lifetimes can't be downcast into, there's no way to abstract lifetimes away. Lifetimes have to stay explicit for the compiler to understand them.

Comment: @Finomnis yes, that makes sense. Does that require any additional explicit constraints, or is it enough for the objects implementing the traits to not contain any references? (Or be references themselves.)

Comment: In general, every struct is `'static` that doesn't contain lifetime annotations (like `struct MyStruct<'a>`).

Comment: @Finomnis Ok that's fine, it is as I thought in that case

Answer (score 1):

In your whole post you assume traits and supertraits work like inheritance in other languages would work, they don't Rust doesn't have inheritance.

You can't use [`downcast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) or [`downcast_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref) because they're not methods of `Any` but inherent methods of `Box<dyn Any + 'static>` and `dyn Any + 'static` respectively, but `dyn DynamicDispatchTrait` is a different type from `dyn Any + 'static`.

Currently I think the only way to achieve what you want is to take `Box<dyn Any + 'static>` and cast it to the specific type you have:

```rust
fn dynamic_function(dynamic: Box<dyn Any + 'static>) -> String {
    let dynamic_named: &dyn Named = if let Some(thing) = dynamic.downcast_ref::<MyType>() {
        thing
    } else if let Some(thing) = dynamic.downcast_ref::<OtherTypeImplementingNamed>() {
        thing
    } else {
        println!("error!");
        return String::from("error");
    };
    
    let s = dynamic_named.get_name();
    return s;
}
```

Once [upcasting is implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/dyn-upcasting-coercion-initiative) you can use that to get a `&dyn Any` from a `&dyn DynamicDispatchTrait`, [lets your code work like you want it to](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=27397b7646f39ec8b81440a5a2f90866) with a little tweak.

`Any` is [automatically implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html#impl-Any-for-T) for every applicable type so you can't and don't need to ever implement it.